# R Shiny quantmod zoomChart and fixed coloring of points

Tags: r, slider, shiny, quantmod

I have a problem regarding `shiny` and the use of sliders, when displaying `chart_Series` and coloured lines . When I am using the slider from the right side, the color is chosen appropriately (mainly red dots). When I use the slider on left side (e.g. looking at the latest data) the color is not chosen appropriately (should be green). I seek for help and I'm thankful for any advise!

```
require(quantmod)
require(shiny)
getSymbols("YHOO")
data <- YHOO
data <- data[1:100,]

col_function <- rep("red",50)
col_function <- c(col_function,  rep("green",50))


plot <- {

  date_range <- index(data)


  if (interactive()) {
    options(device.ask.default = FALSE)
   # Define UI
    ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Time:"),
      sidebarLayout(
        # Sidebar with a slider input
        wellPanel(
          tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftSlide { width:200px;    float:left;}'),
          id = "leftSlide",
          sliderInput("Range", "Choose Date Range:",
                      min = first(date_range), max = last(date_range), value = c(first(date_range),last(date_range)))
        ),

        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("Plot",  width = "150%", height = "500px")
        )
      )
    )

    # Server logic
    server <- function(input, output) {
      output$range <- renderPrint({ input$slider2 })
      output$Plot <- renderPlot({

        x_ti2 <- xts(rep(1, NROW(data)), order.by = index(data))
        x_ti2[1, ] <- 0.5 

      chart_Series(data)
      add_TA(x_ti2, col = col_function, pch = 9, type = 'p', cex = .7)
# Another way below, but the color function is still not working
      #chart_Series(data["2017"], TA = 'add_TA(x_ti, col = col_function, pch = 15, type = "p", cex = .7); add_TA(x_ti2, col = "orange", pch = 9, type = "p", cex = .7)')

      zoom_Chart(paste(input$Range, collapse = "::"))
      })

      observe({
        print(input$Range)
      })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
  }
}  

plot
```

Comment: I have looked at chartSeries as well as chart_series. Both seems to have the same Issue. From my perspective, the zooming of the plot, does not controll the pointed lines. It seems as if they are independent of the chartSeries. However, this still does not explain the reason of the correct zooming from the other side. Furthermore, I tested dateRangeInput: the same problem occured.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a workaround for my own problem:

as far as i can tell, `shiny` will edit the data, but not the coloring-vector (in respective pretty logical...). Therefore you'll have to tell shiny to update the range of the coloring as well.

First of all i transformed the coloring result to an xps-object. Then i added the x_ti2-variable to the original data-matrix and defined a variable with the input$range for your the col_function. The variable needs to part of the Global environment (such that shiny can use it). I hope this will solve some issues, if someone has a similiar problem.